# ggplot number of points according to x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question from the ggplot2 book by Hadley Wickham.
I have this dataframe here:

```
class <- mpg %>%
   group_by(class) %>% 
   summarise(n = n(), hwy = mean(hwy))
```

I want to plot a graph that looks like this: 
[image]

I tried:

```
class %>% ggplot(aes(n, hwy)) +
          geom_count()
```

This doesn't give me the above graph.
Does anybody have any helpful suggestions?

Comment: When asking ggplot2 questions (or any other package that's actively-maintained and somewhat brittle), always always always specify what package version you're using. And/or confirm it breaks with other known-good versions of ggplot2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, thanks to @JakeKaupp:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
class <- mpg %>%
 count(class) %>% 
 mutate(label = paste0("n = ", n))

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
 geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
 stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean, colour = "red", size = 5) +
 geom_text(data = class, aes(y = 10, label = label))
```

[image]

Comment: let me elaborate. in this data, when I code geom_point(), the points all line up straight, but geom_jitter() makes the points look all scattered and not straight. Is geom_jitter() showing an accurate representation of the data?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing the same exercises and using the same book. Here is my codes, but it is pretty much the same as the first answer, but I'll try explain why.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
 geom_jitter(width = 0.05, size = 2) +
 geom_point(aes(y = hwy), data = class, size = 4, color = "red") +
 geom_text(aes(y = 10, label = paste0("n = ", n)), data = class)
```

The result is:
[image]

First, you use the ggplot() function to define the main dataset and aesthetics you want to use. Here, we want to plot the hwy(y-axis) as points against class(x-axis). This is the first line of code.

Second, remember, ggplot2 works by plotting a graph layer by layer. The second line of code is the first layer that we are going to add. Instead of a scatterplot using geom_point(), we want to use jitter plot to avoid overplotting in geom_point(). Here, we are using the same dataset - mpg, and using the same aesthetics (x = class, y = hwy) as we indicated in ggplot(), so we do not change anything. But, to make it look similar to the original plot in the textbook, we want to squeeze the width = 0.05 (or you can adjust this number to 0.1, 0.2 to take a look), and we can add a size = 2 or 1 or 3, it doesn't matter.

Third, we want to create the same red dots in the original graph. This red dot, is the third layer. Here I used geom_point() because these red dots are basically points. However, red dots means the mean value of the y values on corresponding x values. In the original dataset mpg, we do not have this variable. So, here in the second layer of red dots, we need to reset some of the aesthetics and data. We want aesthetics to have y=hwy, this is the same as the ggplot(), but we change the dataset so data = class. Now, the layer knows that each class matches 1 y-axis value which is the hwy as mean value. We have the red dots there, but we also want to shape the size so it looks big, and color to red.

Finally, to add the layer of labels. Any annotation, we use geom_text() layer to do it. We set the aes(y = 10), because this sets the height of the label near position of y = 10. Then we want to set the label value. But here, we only know the n, which is the count. But in the original graph, it is n = integer. So we need to use the paste0() function to concatenate string and numbers. write, label = paste0("n = ", n) to have an effect of n = integer, then, we set the data = class, because we are not using the original mpg.

Then the graph is done. You can also add a title, or x,y-axes labels and so on. But my approach is to write one layer, and run the code to check how it looks, then write another layer. It helps you think about the overall graph. Hope it helps.